# Jfugue 5 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, jfugue

Anyone know how to get JFugue to work on MacOS X 10.10 / JDK 8, talking to a default synthesiser? Even trivial examples which work fine on Windows give results like this, indicating a failure to find a default synth:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1355)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1411)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1378)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDevice(MidiSystem.java:1165)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1115)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSynthesizer(MidiSystem.java:351)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:458)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:392)
    at org.jfugue.player.SequencerManager.getDefaultSequencer(SequencerManager.java:55)
    at org.jfugue.player.SequencerManager.<init>(SequencerManager.java:50)
    at org.jfugue.player.SequencerManager.getInstance(SequencerManager.java:41)
    at org.jfugue.player.ManagedPlayer.<init>(ManagedPlayer.java:47)
    at org.jfugue.player.Player.<init>(Player.java:46)
    at FirstJFugueApp.main(FirstJFugueApp.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I had an old file plumstoneserv.jar in my path which was stopping things working.